# Infinite Sequence {1, 3, 2, 3, 1}

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have an infinite sequence where the start and end of the initial segment is 1. Then many times we will apply the next procedure for each segment.For each pair of consecutive integers we will write its sum.

Sequence buiding:

```
segment-1 {1,1} − seg-2 {1,2,1} − seg-3 {1,3,2,3,1} − seg-4 {1,4,3,5,2,5,3,4,1}
```

How many times the positive integer n will be written on a segment numbered k?

Comment: How is that even remotely related to c++?

Comment: My guess is that this passed through machine translation.

Answer (score 1):

Experimentally it seems that the answer is 2 if k is equal to 1.

Otherwise, the answer is given by [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) phi(k).

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally as well...

First of all. The segment will be odd for `size > 2`.

If `size > 2`, and `n < k/2` (rounding up), n appears two times except if n = 2.